Threads that cannot be stopped properly
I'm newbie in C#, I want to write a small app that checks the disks and in case of write timeout or exceptions (disk disconnection or something) do the computer restart.
It check the amount of disks on computer with code:
        foreach (var drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
    {
        if (drive.IsReady == true)
        {
            double totalSpace = drive.TotalSize;
            int totalSpaceinGB = (int)(totalSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024);

            if (totalSpaceinGB > diskThresholdGb)
            {
                string diskName = drive.Name;
                Console.WriteLine(diskName);

                Console.WriteLine("we start");
                Thread t = new Thread(Listener);
                t.Start(diskName);


            }
        }

    }

and starts thread for each disk passing its name as a parameter through variable diskName.
This code seems to be working normally with one disk always.
However when i use two threads or more(two disks or more) and offline one disk from the disk manager the scripts starts use the same variables and doesnt work normally. Inspite i disconnect one disk (for example D:) other disks are also provide timeouts and errors during program work.
I think this is because of variables
    int failedCounter = 0;
    bool exceptionFlag = false;

Here is the full code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Timers;
using System.Collections;


public class Example
{
    //public static int failedCounter = 0;
    public static int errorRestartThreshold = 5;


    const int delayInMilliseconds = 1000;
    const int diskThresholdGb = 20;
    const string writeDirectoryName = "cdiskmonitorCheck";
    const string writeFileName = "cdiskmonitorCheck.txt";

    const string fullErrorDirectoryName = "c:\\cdiskmonitorCheck";
    const string fullErrorFileName = fullErrorDirectoryName + "\\" + "cdiskmonitorError.log";



    //public bool exceptionFlag = false;

    public static void Main()
    {
        Example e = new Example();
        e.OnStart();

    }
    public void OnStart()
    {

        //Thread t = new Thread(Listener);
        foreach (var drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            if (drive.IsReady == true)
            {
                double totalSpace = drive.TotalSize;
                int totalSpaceinGB = (int)(totalSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024);

                if (totalSpaceinGB > diskThresholdGb)
                {
                    string diskName = drive.Name;
                    Console.WriteLine(diskName);

                    Console.WriteLine("we start");
                    Thread t = new Thread(Listener);
                    t.Start(diskName);


                }
            }

        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private void Listener(object diskLetter)
    {
        Thread thread = null;

        //diskLetter = "fff:";

        int failedCounter = 0;
        bool exceptionFlag = false;

        string fullWriteFolderPath = diskLetter + writeDirectoryName;
        string fullWriteFilePath = fullWriteFolderPath + "\\" + writeFileName;

        while (true)
        {
            var task = Task.Run(() =>
            {

                Console.WriteLine($@"-----------------------------------------------Thread {diskLetter} ----------------------------------------------------");
                exceptionFlag = false;
                DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
                thread = Thread.CurrentThread;

                try
                {
                    //create directory
                    if (!Directory.Exists(fullWriteFolderPath))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(fullWriteFolderPath);
                    }
                    //Console.WriteLine(fullWriteFilePath);

                    //                    Console.WriteLine(start.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff"));
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fullWriteFilePath))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(start.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff"));
                    }

                    failedCounter = 0;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    exceptionFlag = true;
                    //break;
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

                }

                DateTime finish = DateTime.Now;

                System.TimeSpan diff = finish - start;
                int diffInMilliseconds = (int)diff.TotalMilliseconds;

                //we wait for sometime to be 1 second
                if (diffInMilliseconds < delayInMilliseconds)
                {
                    Task.Delay((delayInMilliseconds - diffInMilliseconds)).Wait();
                    //Console.WriteLine((delayInMilliseconds - diffInMilliseconds));
                }

            });


            //Check if task is finished.

            bool isCompletedSuccessfully = task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1200));


            //Console.WriteLine(isCompletedSuccessfully);
            DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
            if (!Directory.Exists(fullErrorDirectoryName))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(fullErrorDirectoryName);
            }

            if (exceptionFlag)
            {
                current = DateTime.Now;
                thread.Abort(true);
                failedCounter++;
                Console.WriteLine("Exception writting to file");
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(fullErrorFileName))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(current.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff") + " exception, counter:" + failedCounter.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!isCompletedSuccessfully)
                {

                    current = DateTime.Now;
                    failedCounter++;
                    Console.WriteLine("Timeoutted writting to file");
                    thread.Abort(true);

                    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(fullErrorFileName))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(current.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff") + " timeoutted, counter:" + failedCounter.ToString());
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    failedCounter = 0;
                    Console.WriteLine($@"Task completed during period. Thread {diskLetter}");
                }

            }

            Console.WriteLine($@"Thread {diskLetter}, fails count:{failedCounter}");



            if (failedCounter >= errorRestartThreshold)
            {
                current = DateTime.Now;
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(fullErrorFileName))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(current.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff") + " we restart server., counter:" + failedCounter.ToString());
                }
            }


        }

    }

}






Working example

It is not really clear to me what your overall goal is, but the mere presence of Thread.Abort suggest that this is probably not the correct approach. If you want to detect when drives are mounted, see Detect drive mount event in c#. Or perhaps you just want to repeatedly retry the writing until it succeed, with some delay between each attempt.

@JonasH Thank you for commenting, i edited my post a little bit as found some results. The problem is when i use 2 disks or more. Looks like threads are concurrent with each other, however the variables are declared in function Listener they should be unique within each thread.

You read Thread.CurrentThread inside Task.Run. That's a prescription for a disaster. Task.Run uses a thread pool under the hood. Meaning it reuses threads. You try to kill a thread that was never yours to begin with. And which is likely processing some other call while you kill it. Why do you even mix threads with tasks? Avoid that, it is hard to do correctly.

Restarting the computer on a disk disconnection or IO failure is not helpful. There are APIs specifically for monitoring disk connections and health. I don't think any exception will be helped by a restart, and code like this may create real problems. Even if you really wanted to do this, I really don't see any reason to use multiple threads at all. just write a single loop checking each disk in sequence. Multi threading is difficult, using it without fully understanding the hazards will cause bugs, many that will be very difficult reproduce and debug.
